# Firebase Admin SDK apply action code for email verification

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

The Firebase [Customize the Email Action Handler guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler)
gives an example of verifying a user's email address on a custom URL to a site hosted through Firebase.

However, I want the custom URL to point to a Firebase cloud function endpoint URL and use admin SDK to verify the oob code instead. But there is no such function as `applyActionCode` for the `admin.auth()`.

Is verifying email through a hosted site using javascript the only way to go? I don't really want to expose the code to the browser.

Comment: Check this thread: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/46 There are few ideas on how to do this from a backend environment.

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this?

Comment: Did you found solution?

Comment: any solution found?

Answer (score 2):

As of 3/8/2020, this `applyActionCode` is not part of the admin sdk. A kludge for this will be to verify the oobCode on the server/backend/cloud function using the rest api
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/#section-send-email-verification.

How?
since you customized the email action handler, assume it is pointed to an endpoint you have  control over (e.g your domain/cloud function), then on the client side, you can obtain the url parameters (including the oobcode) in the url and send to your backend for verification using the REST API.

Comment: why did they remove that from the admin. so annoying

Comment: I'm not sure if this works with password-less signup. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65695558/verifying-password-less-email-signup-in-firebase-admin
(That's me, but I had forgotten my password at the time.)